# Ввод нескольких чисел с записью в массив и передача массива в функцию

Tags: c#, функции, ввод

Вопрос вот в чем: как реализовать консольный ввод от 2 до 5 чисел, при этом вводиться может два числа, а может три числа, та же история с 4 и 5 числами. Логично, что такие числа будут записываться в массив, тут тогда второй вопрос. Возможно ли передать функции часть массива в виде формальных параметров?

Comment: Сначала просите ввести размер массива. Создаёте пустой массив. Потом в цикле вводите очередное число через ReadLine , занося его в массив. Потом передаёте массив куда надо. С чем сложности? Если надо - можете делать выборку из массива ("часть массива"), используя linq функции типа Take (взять первые N элементов) или что вам ещё понадобится.

Comment: вводите числа через пробел и все дела

Comment: @AK, в том и дело, что размерность массива не должна вводиться изначально.

Comment: Ну и не вводите, это необязательно. Вы можете объявить переменную как `int[] arr` а не как `int[5] arr`. Если у вас нет жёсткого требования "прекращать ввод после 5ти чисел", то можете просто использовать цикл while, просто на каждой итерации спрашивать "хотите ввести ещё число". Но тогда лучше использовать `List<int>` я думаю и уже когда будет заполнен сделать `.ToArray()`. В общем, я вижу несколько вариантов реализовать вашу задачу, какой-то из вариантов вам подойдёт. Вон выше ещё один - вводите через пробел, лишние можно отбросить.

Answer (score 2):

Как считать через пробел

```
int[] ReadWithSpace()
{
    return Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
}
```

Например

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

---

Как считать построчно

```
int[] ReadLineByLine()
{
    var ret = new List<int>();
    while(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int parsed))
        ret.Add(parsed);
    return ret.ToArray();
}
```

Например

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```